# Vertical lines for things like "if statements" in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

Is there an add-on or setting that can add vertical lines that link things like "if statements" in Visual Studio 2008?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the CodeRush plugin, ReSharper has a feature called "Highlight Matching Delimiters" (see http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Highlight_Matching_Delimiters) that will show you the matching brace to the one your cursor is on. Not exactly what you asked for, but serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CodeRush from DevExpress: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/navigation.xml (See the "Structural Highlighting" section)

Comment: OMG! How did I live without this?! Thank you!

Comment: @JimDel (or anyone else for that matter) if you find yourself with any CodeRush questions feel free to contact me (details at the bottom of my Community plugin Author page -> http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/RoryBecker)