# Vertical lines for things like “if statements” in Visual Studio 2010 with resharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I saw this question:

[Vertical lines for things like "if statements" in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269756/vertical-lines-for-things-like-if-statements-in-visual-studio-2008)

and wondered if it was possible to do something similar but with Resharper?

(i understand resharper and coderush do similar things and would like to stick with resharper as thats what i'm used to - i would hazard they dont play nice together?)

Is there a simple plugin that adds these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Visual Studio 2010 plugin that does this without Resharper or CodeRush: [StructureAdornment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/203f22f4-3e9f-4dbb-befc-f2606835834e).

Comment: cheers thats what i'm after. shame it's only editable via the registry!

Comment: making the colours semi transparent - #40xxxxxx works well as they dont appear quite so intrusive!

Comment: Worth a try. I actually gave up on this plugin because of the colors.

Comment: turning off the class lines also helps to reduce the clutter - set that entry to #00xxxxxx